# NIFI heap space issue in 1.11.4 version

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am facing heap space memory issue with NIFI 1.11.4 whenever I restart the NIFI application. Initial `bootstrap.conf was Xms4g to Xmx8g`
After restart we are getting java heap space issue so we have increased to 12 GB and it worked fine. After 1 more restart(within 5 days) it is not accepting 12GB as max size and we have changed it to 14GBthen only NIFI got started. Can someone please explain why NIFI is asking for more memory every restart.

```
  ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flushBuffer(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:450)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.write(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:194)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.characters(ToStream.java:1487)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(ToUnknownStream.java:814)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.characters(ToUnknownStream.java:348)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:242)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:92)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:684)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:728)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:343)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.TemplateUtils.parseDto(TemplateUtils.java:63)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addLocalTemplates(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:602)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:410)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.synchronize(FlowController.java:1376)
        at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.load(StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.java:88)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:812)
2021-04-15 05:04:49,699 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@5a6f1342 checkpointed with 14464 Records and 0 Swap Files in 24 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 3 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 1 millis), max Transaction ID 63815
```

Comment: it seems a xml parse issue . either nifi is overloaded or a flow inside it does heavy xml parse operation. consider to check flows to spot problematical xml operation

Comment: xml parse--> you mean to say the flows and templates created in nifi are huge which is causing this issue?

Comment: that might cause it. template definitions pile up in flow.xml.gz under conf directory. nifi tries to load that xml. deleting template definitions and unnecessary flows may help.

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you changed different parameters.

```
xms4g
```

Is actually the starting memory configuration. While `xmx8g` is the maximum allowable.

You should try and set both to 8g (If that is the setting that is recommended for your system).
Thanks